# Visual Studio extension: How to make editor text behave like a link

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, visual-studio-sdk

I would like to write a Visual Studio extension, that makes a part of the text behave like a link: blue, underlined on hover, open a URL on click. (Like the default editor works for `http://...` texts.)

I can do classification (coloring) and also custom adornments and commands, so I could probably make this "manually", but I wonder if there is an easier way to do that.

I am interested to do this in normal Visual Studio (2017 or newer), not VS Code.

Comment: Hi Gaspar, any update for this issue? If Sergey's answer can help resolve your issue, you can consider marking it as answer after the issue is solved. Just a reminder:)

Comment: I will test it on Monday and mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UrlTag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.tagging.urltag?view=visualstudiosdk-2017).

On how to use tags see [Walkthrough: Highlight text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-highlighting-text?view=vs-2019) and [Visual Studio 2017 Extension development tutorial part 5: Highlight code in Editor](https://michaelscodingspot.com/visual-studio-2017-extension-development-tutorial-highlight-code-in-editor/).

Comment: Thx! I knew there must be something like this, but I couldn't find it. I will try.